# How to obtain data from csv files using regex in python

Tags: regex, python-3.x, csv

I am trying to filter a csv file from a column contains many minus numbers.

I found a source code on the website, which worked on small lists, but it does not work on data from a csv file.

here is an example of the data I have.

```
691
609
627
211
-226
921
829
1
972
173
181
-66
-96
573
```

and here is the code I am using

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import numpy as np
import re

import csv
from re import findall

ful = pd.read_csv(r'/home/aziz/Desktop/testminplus.csv')
ful1 = ful[0:]

#full = ['1', '-3']
full = ful1

regex = re.compile(r'(-\d*)')
# use only one of the following lines, whichever you prefer
#filtered = filter(lambda i: not regex.search(i), full)
filtered = [i for i in full if not regex.search(i)]
print(filtered)
```

The results are as the following:

```
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '8', '2', '3', '\n', '0', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '6', '0', '9', '\n', '1', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '6', '2', '7', '\n', '2', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '2', '1', '1', '\n', '3', ' ', ' ', ' ', '2', '2', '6', '\n', '4', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '9', '2', '1', '\n', '5', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '8', '2', '9', '\n', '6', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '1', '\n', '7', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '9', '7', '2', '\n', '8', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '1', '7', '3', '\n', '9', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '1', '8', '1', '\n', '1', '0', ' ', ' ', ' ', '6', '6', '\n', '1', '1', ' ', ' ', ' ', '9', '6', '\n', '1', '2', ' ', ' ', ' ', '5', '7', '3', '\n', '1', '3', ' ', ' ', ' ', '8', '9', '5', '\n', '1', '4', ' ', ' ', ' ', '1', '1', '8', '\n', '1', '5', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '7', '\n', '1', '6', ' ', ' ', '6', '9', '8', '\n', '1', '7', ' ', ' ', ' ', '3', '5', '1', '\n', '1', '8', ' ', ' ', ' ', '9', '3', '3', '\n', '1', '9', ' ', ' ', ' ', '9', '3', '2', '\n', '2', '0', ' ', ' ', ' ', '7', '3', '2', '\n', '2', '1', ' ', ' ', '6', '6', '0', '\n', '2', '2', ' ', ' ', '4', '6', '5', '\n', '2', '3', ' ', ' ', ' ', '3', '4', '5', '\n', '2', '4', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '1', '8', '\n', '2', '5', ' ', ' ', ' ', '1', '2', '0', '\n', '2', '6', ' ', ' ', '2', '7', '0', '\n', '2', '7', ' ', ' ', '2', '3', '3', '\n', '2', '8', ' ', ' ', '1', '5', '2', '\n', '2', '9', ' ', ' ', ' ', '1', '8', '6', '\n', '3', '0', ' ', ' ', '3', '9', '6', '\n', '3', '1', ' ', ' ', '5', '3', '5', '\n', '3', '2', ' ', ' ', ' ', '3', '5', '9', '\n', '3', '3', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '1', '\n', '3', '4', ' ', ' ', '5', '3', '3', '\n', '3', '5', ' ', ' ', ' ', '8', '1', '2', '\n', '3', '6', ' ', ' ', ' ', '5', '4', '6']
```

The desired output is something like the following:

```
123
213
2
5
```

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Is there a requirement to use pandas/regex here? Is your question ultimately - "How can I get a list of non-negative numbers from a file" or there abouts?

Comment: No requirements. I just need the results shown above...and yes, I need to exclude the negative numbers from the csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've just got a file with one number per line (and not an actual CSV file with multiple fields which doesn't appear to be your case) then you can do:

```
with open('/home/aziz/Desktop/testminplus.csv') as fin:
    # generator to yield each line as an integer
    data = (int(line) for line in fin)
    # list-comp to only include positive numbers...
    positive = [n for n in data if n >= 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandas solution is probably an overkill here, but also works quite well

```
import pandas as pd
# read file
df = pd.read_csv("/home/aziz/Desktop/testminplus.csv", 
                 header=None, 
                 converters={0: int}) # spits an error if non-numbers are present
# filter positives
df = df[df[0]>=0]
# write back 
df.to_csv("/home/aziz/Desktop/positives_only.csv", 
          header=False, 
          index=False)
```